# My user font-end display got messed up!, But if I use the admin account.. It's working fine

Tags: database, wordpress, user-interface, debugging, caching

You can see the image here:
[actual display of the front-end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdPk6.png)

I'm Using Wordpress and thrive theme.

Comment: Do you have a caching plugin installed? If so, what happens when you disable it?

Comment: Server side caching is also something to consider. Sometimes you have .css?version=x.x.x -- that needs to be changed or removed or your browser will not show changes... If you have control I change version to be a timestamp during development therefore the "version number" is different every second :)

Comment: No Caching plugin were installed=D I tried to disabled all my plugins one by one. But still can't figure out the cause.